# Render ViewComponent inside html string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Lets say I have a ViewComponent named MyComponent.

As of ASP.NET Core 1.1 I can render this ViewComponent by writing this inside a razor view .cshtml page:

```
 <vc:my-component></vc:my-component>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
@{string myHtml = "<vc:my-component></vc:my-component>";}

@(new HtmlString(myHtml))
```

I installed and tried RazorEngine by doing this, but this did not work:

```
string template = "<vc:my-component></vc:my-component>";
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "messageTemplateKey", null, new { Name = "some model data" });
ViewBag.result = result;
```

then in the .chtml file:

```
 @(new HtmlString(ViewBag.result))
```

The backstory to this is that I've created a ViewComponent with some logic on how to handle image files, now I want to search and replace all img tags in some html with my ViewComponent. Before I do that I need to make sure this even works.

Comment: Since there are examples of rendering a view to a string on stack overflow, wouldn't it work to create a view and put code in it to use your view component and then just render the view to a string?  I'm pretty sure that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I moved the view code from the Default.cshtml for MyComponent to a partial view (**_myPartial**).
Then I used a IViewRenderService inspired by [this post](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/).

Then I could render and get my html string after passing in the viewmodel by doing this:

```
 var result = ViewRenderService.RenderToString("_myPartial", viewModel);
```

Comment: @TobiOwolawi this example is a view component. I just had to move the html/razor code from the view components Default.cshtml to a partial view. In that way I could both use the view component and retrieve the rendered html by using the partial view underneath

Answer (score 2):

Check the code at this url on github:

https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/b424e9b8b03d31d67f3cce59f09ab17f

---

### Code

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

  public async Task<string> RenderViewComponent(string viewComponent, object args) {

    var sp = HttpContext.RequestServices;

    var helper = new DefaultViewComponentHelper(
        sp.GetRequiredService<IViewComponentDescriptorCollectionProvider>(),
        HtmlEncoder.Default,
        sp.GetRequiredService<IViewComponentSelector>(),
        sp.GetRequiredService<IViewComponentInvokerFactory>(),
        sp.GetRequiredService<IViewBufferScope>());

    using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
        var context = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, NullView.Instance, ViewData, TempData, writer, new HtmlHelperOptions());
        helper.Contextualize(context);
        var result = await helper.InvokeAsync(viewComponent, args);
        result.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        return writer.ToString();
    }
  }}
```

---

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.